# Searching A Link List In C

Tags: c, list

I'm trying to search a link list in c, I can get it to match my search string with the first node but not the next any ideas why. Here's my code:

```
void fnSearchList(struct listnode *ptrH, char strName[50])
{
    struct listnode *ptrTemp = ptrH;
    int nCount = 0;
//  nRet = strcmp(strName, ptrH->arcFirstName);
//  printf("%i", nRet);
    if(!ptrH)
    {
        /* Empty List */
        printf("\n\nEmpty List \n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while(ptrTemp->ptrNext)
        {
            nRet = strcmp(strName, ptrTemp->arcFirstName);
            if(nRet == 0)
            {
                printf("The value %s has been located\n", ptrTemp->arcFirstName);
                nCount++;
            }
            ptrTemp = ptrTemp->ptrNext;
        }

        if(!nCount)
            printf("\t\tValue not found within the list\n");
        else
            printf("\t\tA total of %d were found\n", nCount);
    }   
    printf("The list totals %d\n", fnTotalList(ptrH));
}
```

I have marked a few things out as I was testing to see if the `strcmp` was working which it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your while loop should be:

```
while (ptrTemp)
```

Otherwise it will not look a the last element in the list

Comment: Isnt it crazy how one little thing can make the code work I was looking at that the wife even said try removing it but I never did hehe. She should be the one doing the programming HAHAHA

Answer (score 1):

The condition to check for the `while` loop should be `while(ptrTemp)` and not 
 `while(ptrTemp->ptrNext)`. That is because you already change `ptrTemp` to point to the next node in the list by doing

```
ptrTemp = ptrTemp->ptrNext;
```

So your code skips the last node in the list because `lastNode->ptrNext == NULL` is `true`.
Also, note that `strName` parameter of your function `fnSearchList` is a pointer to `char` type and not an array of 50 `char`. You can write it as:

```
void fnSearchList(struct listnode *ptrH, char *strName) {
    // stuff
}
```

They are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

***Change***:

```
while(ptrTemp->ptrNext)
```

***To***:

```
while(ptrTemp)
```